# Google Trends fetchComponent doesn't work anymore, any alternatives?

Tags: google-trends

There is no public Google Trends API to deal with, [this article](http://techslides.com/hacking-the-google-trends-api) shows a hack of how to use `fetchComponent` and was working for almost two years without any problems! But, this hack doesn't work!

**Example:**
`https://trends.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=html5,jquery&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300`